# React Native add typed text to an index in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Am trying to create a bus ticket booking app, for every seat chosen the client has to provide data for it like full name, phone number, passport number and residence. The way i have done is i supply the seats chosen array to a flatlist which renders a form for every seat like below.

```
renderinputs = ({item,index}) =>{
    //let index = item.seatNo;
    return <View style={{marginTop:5}}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Passenger Details For Seat: {item.seatNo}</Text>

      <TextInput
      key={index}
        onChangeText={e => this.props.fullnamezchanged(index, e)}
        placeholder={'Full Name'}
        style={{
          height: 40,
          width:'80%',
          borderColor: "gray",
          borderWidth: 1,
          marginTop: 8,
          borderRadius:8
        }}
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
       ref={(ref) => this.searchInput = ref}
       value={this.props.fullnamez[index]}
      />

      <TextInput
      
        onChangeText={e => this.props.phonenumberzchanged(index, e)}
        placeholder={'Phone Number'}
        style={{
          height: 40,
          width:'80%',
          borderColor: "gray",
          borderWidth: 1,
          marginTop: 8,
          borderRadius:8
        }}
      />
      <TextInput
      
        onChangeText={e => this.props.passportzchanged(index, e)}
        placeholder={"ID/Passport"}
        style={{
          height: 40,
          width:'80%',
          borderColor: "gray",
          borderWidth: 1,
          marginTop: 8,
          borderRadius:8
        }}
      />
      <TextInput
      
        onChangeText={e => this.props.residencezchanged(index, e)}
        placeholder={'Residence'}
        style={{
          height: 40,
          width:'80%',
          borderColor: "gray",
          borderWidth: 1,
          marginTop: 8,
          borderRadius:8
        }}
      />
      <View
  style={{
    borderBottomColor: 'black',
    borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
    marginTop:5
  }}
/>
      </View>
  }
```

[the render inputs function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8wTq.png)
[render inputs second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHy4c.png)

Am using redux to manage state so the action when a fullnamechanges:
[fullnamechanged action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSrUt.png)

```
export const fullnamezchanged = (index, e) =>{
        return async(dispatch)=>{
            dispatch({type:FULLNAMEZ_CHANGED,payload:{index, e}})
        }
    }
```

in the reducer:
[fullnamechangedreducer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl35F.png)
case FULLNAMEZ_CHANGED:

```
return{...state,fullnamez:addAfter(state.fullnamez,action.payload.e,action.payload.index)}
   default:
     return state;
```

}

```
 const addAfter = (array, val,ind) => {
    return array.splice(ind,val);
}
```

empty array
And it returns
the numbers represent the seat chosen.
i would like it to return fullnamez['react','native','react']
When i changed the index to index of value in seats array i get empty array

Comment: Add the code to the question instead of adding screenshots. Now we can't read them.

Comment: Sorry about i had trouble with the code indentation feature but i have added code now